# Is there any built-in method in RoR to fill zero for integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I want "00001" instead of "1", apart from writing my own filling zero method, is there any built in method can help me fill in zero for the integer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
puts "%05d" % 1    # 00001
```

See: [String::%](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000770), [Kernel::sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005962)

Here's what's going on.  The `"%05d"` to the left of the `%` is a C style format specifier.  The variable on the right side of the % is the thing to be formatted.  The format specifier can be decoded like this:

- % -   beginning of format specifier
- 0 -   Pad with leading zeros
- 5 -   Make it 5 characters long
- d -   The thing being formatted is an integer

If you were formatting multiple things, you'd put them in an array:

```
"%d - %s" % [1, "One"]    # => 1 - one
```

Comment: simple and elegant, but I don't understand the code. it seems a little bit strange for me.

Comment: %d means decimal, which refers to the value after the %, the 05 means to pad zeros to the decimal to make it length 5.

Comment: The formating is based C's printf.  It is used by lots of languages so it is worth learning.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf

Answer (score 4):

```
puts 1.to_s.rjust(5,'0')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
an_int = 1
'%05d' % an_int #=> 00001
```